# Suppose that the sequence ${a_n}$ is monotone. Prove that it converges iff ${a_n^2}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Regarding the title, can you start the proof in one direction by supposing that ${a_n}^2$ converges and ${a_n}$ is monotone, then ${a_n} < {a_n}^2$. In that case, ${a_n}$ is bounded above by ${a_n}^2$ so that ${a_n}$ converges? I feel like there are some gaps in that proof.

Comment: @andybenji I think OP means sequence not series.

Comment: @frank000 duly noted, thanks

Comment: For the $[\Longrightarrow]$ part, observe that if $(a_n)$ is monotone then $(a_n^2)$ is *eventually* monotone.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Since $\{a^2_n\}$ converges, $\{a^2_n\}$ is bounded, and hence $\{a_n\}$ is also bounded. Moreever,   $\{a_n\}$  is monotone. So by the **monotone bound theorem:**,  $\{a_n\}$ converges.

> **Monotone bound theorem: Every monotone and bounded sequence  $\{a_n\}$ must converge.**

Comment: Can we say then that if {a_n} is monotone then }a_n^2} is monotone (for the other direction)?

Comment: It needs take time to discuss because it will be complex if we consider $\{a^2_n\}$. You should consider $a^2_{n+1}-a^2_n=(a_{n+1}-a_n)(a_{n+1}+a_n).$